# How to reuse connections with PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager?

Tags: ssl, httpclient, connection-pooling, reusability

I am currently using PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager for one of my Java Spring boot service. I am am observing that the connections are not being reused and they are closed every time.

Once the number of connections has reached the maximum pool size, the connections are closed. Is there a way for us to avoid closing the connection/SSL handshake for every request?

Note: We do have the keep-alive header being sent by both the client and the server.

This is what the config looks like:

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(SSLContext.getDefault());

Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory> create()
.register("https", sslsf)
.register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory())
.build();

PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
poolingManager.setMaxTotal(150);
poolingManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(50);
poolingManager.setValidateAfterInactivity(1000);

CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
.setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
.setConnectionManager(poolingManager)
.setSSLContext(SSLContext.getDefault())
.setConnetionManagerShared(true)
```